# How would I use rundll32.exe to run a pyd?

Tags: c, rundll32, pyd

I made a .pyd file with this source:

```py
def hello():
    print("Hello world")
```

and I want to run hello() from rundll32 (Or any C code in general)

I tried `rundll32 hello.pyd,hello()` and `rundll32 hello.pyd,hello` but neither worked

I also looked through the C code, and did not find anything useful

Comment: I also compiled the pyx as a dll to see if that would make a difference, but it didnt

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rundll32 but use C.

Inspect your hello.pyd as a dll with this tool :
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

So you will see : if your file is a real .dll.

If it is real DLL :

- you will see what is exported in your hello.pyd
- you can use IMPLIB to produce a .lib file for linking .

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/IMPLIB.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Tool_for_Win32

- declare your function in your c source for example

  void hello();

Comment: the only function exported is PyInit_test
I tried recompiling it as just `print("hello world") and running the function with rundll32 and it not work